# How to create multiple labels without them all disappearing at once?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I used the code below to create a label every time a button is pressed, then have the label move to a specific location, and then have it delete.

My problem is it can't create multiple labels because it's deleting the label way too soon, because it removes everything named `label`.

**How can I fix this so it creates multiple labels that only get deleted when a label individually completes its animation?**

A solution I've thought of, but can't figure out is where you have it create a label with a different name such as label1, label2, and so on, so that way it can delete a specific label when it completes it's animation, instead of deleting all of them.

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

func createLabel() {

    // Find the button's width and height
    let labelWidth = label.frame.width

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.width

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
    let xwidth = viewWidth - labelWidth

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))

    // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
    label.center.x = xoffset + labelWidth / 2
    label.center.y = 300

    label.font = UIFont(name:"Riffic Free", size: 18.0)
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "+1"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}

func clearLabel() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, delay: 0.4, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

        self.label.center = CGPoint(x: 265, y: 75 )

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        self.label.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    createLabel()
    clearLabel()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    createLabel()
    clearLabel()
}
```

There are two issues. The first is that you are doing the animation and removal before you even give the label a chance to become part of the interface. You need to introduce a delay (you can use my `delay` utility, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994):

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    createLabel()
    delay(0.1) {
        clearLabel()
    }
}
```

The second problem, as you have rightly said, is that you have one `label` instance variable, which you are using to share the label between `createLabel` and `clearLabel`. Thus another label cannot come along during the animation.

But you don't actually *need* any instance variable. So get rid of your `label` declaration completely! Instead, modify `createLabel` so that it actually *creates* the label (i.e. calls `UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))`) as a *local* variable, and then *returns* a reference to label it creates, like this:

```
func createLabel() -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    // ...
    return label
}
```

... And then just have `clearLabel` take that *same* label as a *parameter* so that it moves that label and removes it at the end of the animation, like this:

```
func clearLabel(_ label : UILabel) {
    // ...
}
```

Your `clicked` implementation will thus look like this, passing the label out of `createLabel` and into `clearLabel`:

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let label = self.createLabel()
    delay(0.1) {
        self.clearLabel(label)
    }
}
```

(The remaining details of modifying `createLabel` and `clearLabel` to make that work are left as an exercise for the reader.)

Now each tap on the button creates and animates and removes a new label, independently of whatever else may have happened before.

[image]

Comment: I changed clicked into what you suggested and implemented your delay function.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean for the modification of `createLabel`, can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand how to modify `createLabel` and create the parameter function because if delete the declaration of `label` then the random location spawn of the label function won't work. Can you post code to go with it?

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code you had for `clearLabel`?

Comment: `clearLabel` did not change significantly. Neither did `createLabel`. Basically I'm using your code throughout. The only difference for `clearLabel` is that now there is no `self.label`; instead, there is the label that is passed _into_ `clearLabel` as a _parameter_, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing now. I'm showing you what I did in order to implement your code, and you can see from the screencast that it does what you want done. There should be _no_ reference to `self` anywhere in your code at this point; the `label` is the _local_ variable `label` in each method.